# DeprecationWarning: The longpolling-port is a deprecated alias to the gevent-port option, please use the latter

Tags: odo

Odoo version 16.0

Python version 3.10

While running service it gives below warning in terminal

odoo-16.0/odoo/tools/config.py:565

DeprecationWarning: The longpolling-port is a deprecated alias to the gevent-port option, please use the latter

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The longpolling-port option has been deprecated in Odoo 16.0 and you need to change it in  the default odoorc file or odoo config to `gevent_port`

or you can set the value to False:

```
longpolling_port = False
```